# browserHistoory.push does not work in react.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I work on react ecommerce website In my login component when the person click on submit button on form then its check the user is authenticated or not in useeffecr if its authenticated then its redirect to / by using history.push but it cannot work it vanishes the nothing show on the site I dont know why.The command  i used to install react-history is npm i react-history --force
I used force because its throw some dependency error while installing without --force

Here is the error that throw on console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'oneOf')
at ./node_modules/react-history/PropTypes.js (PropTypes.js:8:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/react-history/Actions.js (Actions.js:10:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/react-history/index.js (index.js:6:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

```
import React, { Fragment,useRef,useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import "./LoginSignUp.css"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MailOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import LackOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Key'
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Key'
import FaceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Face'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux"
import { clearErrors,login } from '../../actions/userAction';
import {useAlert} from "react-alert";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader"
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'react-history'
export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const LoginSignUp = ({browserHistory}) => {
  

   const dispatch=useDispatch();
   
   const alert=useAlert()
    

   const {error,loading,isAuthenticated}=useSelector((state)=>state.user)
    const loginTab=useRef(null);
    const registerTab=useRef(null);
    const switcherTab=useRef(null);


    const [loginEmail,setLoginEmail]=useState("");
    const [loginPassword,setLoginPassword]=useState("");

    const [user,setUser]=useState({
        name:"",
        email:"",
        password:""
    })
    
      const {name,email,password}=user;
      const {avatar,setAvatar}=useState;
      const {avatarPreview,setAvatarPreview}=useState("/Profile.png")

    const loginSubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(login(loginEmail,loginPassword))
    }
    
    
    const registerSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const myForm=new FormData();
        myForm.set("name",name);
        myForm.set("email",email);
        myForm.set("password",password);
        myForm.set("avatar",avatar);
        console.log("Form Submit");
    }
 const registerDataChange=(e)=>{
    if(e.target.name==="avatar"){
     
        const reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onload=()=>{
            if(reader.readyState===2){ 
                //there is three state 0 means initial,1 means processing,3 means ready
                setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
                setAvatar(reader.result);

            }
        }
      
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

    }else{
     
        setUser({...user,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})


    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
  if(error){
    alert.error(error);
    dispatch(clearErrors())
  }
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    browserHistory.push('/');
  }
},[dispatch,error,alert,isAuthenticated,browserHistory])
    
  const switchTabs = (e, tab) => {
    if (tab === "login") {
      switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutral");
      switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToRight");

      registerTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutralForm");
      loginTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToLeft");
    }
    if (tab === "register") {
      switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToRight");
      switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutral");

      registerTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutralForm");
      loginTab.current.classList.add("shiftToLeft");
    }
  };


  return (
    
    <Fragment>
    {loading ? (
      <Loader />
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="LoginSignUpContainer">
          <div className="LoginSignUpBox">
            <div>
              <div className="login_signUp_toggle">
                <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "login")}>LOGIN</p>
                <p onClick={(e) => switchTabs(e, "register")}>REGISTER</p>
              </div>
              <button ref={switcherTab}></button>
            </div>
            <form className="loginForm" ref={loginTab} onSubmit={loginSubmit}>
              <div className="loginEmail">
                <MailOutlineIcon />
                <input
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  required
                  value={loginEmail}
                  onChange={(e) => setLoginEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="loginPassword">
                <LockOpenIcon />
                <input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  required
                  value={loginPassword}
                  onChange={(e) => setLoginPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <Link to="/password/forgot">Forget Password ?</Link>
              <input type="submit" value="Login" className="loginBtn" />
            </form>
            <form
              className="signUpForm"
              ref={registerTab}
              encType="multipart/form-data"
              onSubmit={registerSubmit}
            >
              <div className="signUpName">
                <FaceIcon />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  required
                  name="name"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={registerDataChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="signUpEmail">
                <MailOutlineIcon />
                <input
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  required
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={registerDataChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="signUpPassword">
                <LockOpenIcon />
                <input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  required
                  name="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={registerDataChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div id="registerImage">
                <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="avatar"
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={registerDataChange}
                />
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Register" className="signUpBtn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )}
  </Fragment>
  )
  
}

export default LoginSignUp
```

//The Above code is my LoginSign code

My App.js code is

```
import './App.css';
import Header from "./component/layout/Header/Header.js"
import Footer from "./component/layout/Footer/Footer.js"
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,  Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import webFont from "webfontloader"
import React from 'react';
import Home from './component/layout/Home/Home';

import ProductDetaileNew from './component/product/ProductDetaileNew';
import Search from './component/product/Search';
import TestProduct from './component/product/TestProduct';
import Products from './component/product/Products';
import LoginSignUp from './component/User/LoginSignUp';
function App() {

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    webFont.load({
      google:{
        families:["Roboto","Droid Sans","chilanka"]
      }
    })
  })
  return (
   <Router>
    <Header/>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetaileNew/>}/>
        <Route path='/products' element={<Products/>}/>
        <Route path='/products/:keyword' element={<Products/>}/>
        <Route path='/search' element={<Search/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignUp/>}/>
        </Routes>
   
    <Footer/>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const LoginSignUp = ({browserHistory}) => {
```

You have two variables named `browserHistory` here. Any code that's inside the component will be using the one from the prop, not the exported const.

That could still work if you were passing a prop in, but you do not pass in any props:

```
<Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignUp/>}/>
```

The fix is likely to not create a second browserHistory variable:

```
const LoginSignUp = () => {
```